# Using the builtin function __builtin_add_overflow_p in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, built-in, integer-overflow

I was wondering on how to use this function, because I get an error when I do this:

```
#define INT_ADD_OVERFLOW_P(a, b) \
__builtin_add_overflow_p (a, b, (__typeof__ ((a) + (b))) 0);
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
__int main()
{
    int x1 = -1073741826;
    int y1 = -1073741826;
    int z1 = x1+y1; 
    INT_ADD_OVERFLOW_P ( x1,  y1);
    printf("%d\n",z1);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile_OUTPUT:

```
gcc -c -Wall -D DEBUG  tempFile.c
gcc tempFile.o -o tempFile
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'tempFile' failed//new error after update
```

Compile_ERROR:

```
tempFile.c: In function ‘main’:
tempFile.c:10:1: warning: implicit declaration of function        ‘__builtin_add_overflow_p’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
tempFile.o: In function `main':
tempFile.c:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `__builtin_add_overflow_p'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [tempFile] Error 1
```

Here is a link to the functions I want to use:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html

Here is the makefile that i'm using:

```
compiler=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -D DEBUG 
programname=tempFile

all: $(programname)

$(programname): $(programname).o
    $(compiler) $(programname).o -o $(programname)

$(programname).o: $(programname).c
    $(compiler) $(CFLAGS) $(programname).c

clean:
    rm *o $(programname)
```

Comment: What version of gcc are you using?

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Comment: also tried it with clang compiler

Comment: There's your problem - those builtins were added in a later version. (5.something I think)

Comment: Upgrading to ubuntu 16.04 to install gcc 5 will tell you how it goes

Comment: So I upgraded to 16.04, running gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 - Got a new error "Makefile:8: recipe for target 'tempFile' failed" added it to the question. I still also get the error undefined refence to __builtin_add_overflow_p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__builtin_add_overflow_p` is supported by GCC 7 that has not been released yet

- [Current development](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html)
- [6.2.0 (Latest releases)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html)

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out how to use the built-in functions. Instead of using __builtin_add_overflow_p I used __builtin_add_overflow

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(void)
{
  int x1 = -1073741826;
  int y1 = -1073741826;
  int z1 = x1 + y1; 
  int temp;

  printf("%d\n", __builtin_add_overflow(x1, y1, &temp));
  if (__builtin_add_overflow(x1, y1, &temp)) {
    printf("overflow detected");
  }
  printf("%d\n", z1);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference between the two calls?

Comment: The built-in functions that ends with a p are similar to __builtin_add_overflow, __builtin_sub_overflow and __builtin_mul_overflow. The difference is that the functions that end with a p  don't store the result of the arithmetic operation anywhere and the last argument is not a pointer, but some expression with integral type other than enumerated or Boolean type. Here is a link to integral types http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: I don´t see why this would be an answer. Your question asked for how to use one function, and your solution is using an other function which has a different definition? Put it as a comment to your question instead saying "not my problem anymore, but question remains".

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `__builtin_add_overflow_p` to implement something a bit like a saturating addition:

```c
#define sadd(a, b)                                             \
    ({                                                         \
        __auto_type _a = (a);                                  \
        __auto_type _b = (b);                                  \
        __builtin_add_overflow_p(_a, _b, _a) ? _a : (_a + _b); \
    })
```

Example:

```c
uint8_t foo = 253;

foo = sadd(foo, 1); // foo = 254
foo = sadd(foo, 1); // foo = 255
foo = sadd(foo, 1); // foo = 255
```

This is using a GCC extension called [Statement Expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html), and `__auto_type` is explained here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html.

The call to `__builtin_add_overflow_p` is saying, if there would be an overflow from addition of `a` and `b` (the first 2 arguments), stored in `a` (the 3rd argument), return the original value of `a`, otherwise return the result of the addition between `a` and `b`.

You could also probably use `__builtin_add_overflow` if you added a 3rd variable `c`, and returned that if the result didn't overflow, otherwise return `a`.